# Accessing a hash inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a coding problem where I have 3 lines of text and I have to calculate the words that appear the most in those lines. The answer is: ['it','really','will'] because the text is:

*This is a really really really cool experiment really
Cute little experiment
Will it work maybe it will work do you think it will it will*

Everything works in the code below except the highest_count_words_across_lines method. It's supposed to return ['it','really','will'] but instead returns 2 hashes inside an array:`[{"a"=>1, "cool"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "is"=>1, "really"=>4, "this"=>1}, {"cute"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "little"=>1}, {"do"=>1, "it"=>4, "maybe"=>1, "think"=>1, "will"=>4, "work"=>2, "you"=>1}]`.

I've tried iterating through a hash with multiple select statements to no avail.

**This is my full code so far:**

```
class LineAnalyzer
      attr_accessor :highest_wf_count, :highest_wf_words, :content, :line_number #Implement the following read-only attributes in the LineAnalyzer class. 

  def initialize(content, line)   
      @content = content   #* initialize the content and line_number attributes
      @line_number = line   
      @highest_wf_count = 0
      calculate_word_frequency()  
  end

  def calculate_word_frequency()
    @highest_wf_words = Hash.new
    words = @content.downcase.split
    words.each { |w|
      if @highest_wf_words.has_key?(w)
        @highest_wf_words[w] += 1
      else
        @highest_wf_words[w] = 1
      end
    }
    @highest_wf_words.sort_by { |word, count| count }
    @highest_wf_words.each do |key, value|
      if value > @highest_wf_count
        @highest_wf_count = value
      end
    end
  end

  def highest_wf_count= (number)
    @highest_wf_count = number
  end

end


class Solution
  attr_reader :analyzers, :highest_count_across_lines, :highest_count_words_across_lines # Implement the following read-only attributes in the Solution class.

  def initialize() 
    @analyzers = []
    highest_count_across_lines = nil
    highest_count_words_across_lines = []
  end

  def analyze_file()
    File.foreach('test.txt').with_index(1) do |content, line|
      line_analyzer = LineAnalyzer.new(content, line)
      @analyzers << line_analyzer
    end
  end

  def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency()

     @highest_count_across_lines = analyzers.map(&:highest_wf_count).max
     @highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.select { |k,v| v = @highest_count_across_lines }
  end


  def print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines() 
    "The following words have the highest frequency per line: \n  #{highest_count_words_across_lines} (appears in line #{line_num} \n"  
  end
end
```

**This is the error message I get:**

```
Failures:

  1) Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
     Failure/Error: expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"]

       expected collection contained:  ["it", "really", "will"]
       actual collection contained:    [{"a"=>1, "cool"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "is"=>1, "really"=>4, "this"=>1}, {"cute"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "little"=>1}, {"do"=>1, "it"=>4, "maybe"=>1, "think"=>1, "will"=>4, "work"=>2, "you"=>1}]
       the missing elements were:      ["it", "really", "will"]
       the extra elements were:        [{"a"=>1, "cool"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "is"=>1, "really"=>4, "this"=>1}, {"cute"=>1, "experiment"=>1, "little"=>1}, {"do"=>1, "it"=>4, "maybe"=>1, "think"=>1, "will"=>4, "work"=>2, "you"=>1}]
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.26418 seconds (files took 0.38 seconds to load)
19 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:31 # Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
```

I've tried iterating through the hashes within an array but kept getting an error message. I am trying to find the keys where the values (counts) are equal to the highest count (4). So the final answer should be ["it","really","will"]. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Merge the array of hash into one single hash:
lets say, your array of hash is `arrayOfHash`

```
hash = arrayOfHash.inject(:merge)
```

**Step 2**

collect the keys which contains the maximum values in that single `hash` we created in step 1:

```
result = arrayOfHash.collect{|k, v| k if v == arrayOfHash.values.max}.compact
```